# Php отправка эмейла по двум адресам

Tags: php, email

Эмм, не пойму что не так.
`$to = "mail1@gmail.com, mail2@gmail.com"` - отправляется.

А если:

```
$from = "mail2@gmail.com";
$to = "mail1@gmail.com," .$from;
```

на первое мыло приходит, а на второе нет.

Как это правильно прописать?

Answer (score 0):

Недостающий символ пробела за запятой. Получатели разделяться символом `,`  а не `,` и размер блока (включая `RCPT TO:` и `<CRLF>` не может превышать 512 байт и длинна адреса получателя не может превышать 128 байт.

```
RCPT TO:<forward-path> [ SP <rcpt-parameters> ] <CRLF>
```

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-3.3
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-4.1.1.3

А еще советую глянуть

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821

*PS: Зачастую на длину блока уже все кладут. Но стандарт есть стандарт.*